# Using readfile on multiple devices?

Tags: php, html, file-io, header

I'm having a bad time with the readfile function on php. I'm setting up a web file server, but many  of the users have problems with the downloads.
Basically, I'm using Chrome on my computer and everything works fine. Some of the users have problems on Android browser: they get a .bin file instead og .doc, or get a correct .doc file, but they can't open it. Also, someone gets a corrupted .doc file on the computer.
I have read many questions on this site but they weren't so helpful.

Since I have tried many solutions, I will post a shortened code snippet to give an idea of what I am trying to accomplish. I am using apache2, couldn't it be a configuration problem?
Does someone have my problems too?

```
<?php

//here I take the user, the pwd and the file RELATIVE path
//there are no errors here

header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary'); 
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="' . $name . '"'); 
readfile($file);


?>
```

EDIT: full code

```
<?php

session_start();

$data = $_SESSION['data'];
$name = $_GET['name'];

if (isset($data)) {
    //private file
    $file = "path/".$data."/".$name;
} else {
    //public file
    $file = "path/public/".$name;
}
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary"); 
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . $name . "\""); 
readfile($file);


?>
```

Comment: What is the actual Content-Type of the file?  Is it `application/msword`?

Comment: I doubt that the issue is in php's readfile function. If people are getting a file with the wrong name (i.e. *.bin), then the problem would be with your code that sets the `content-disposition` header where the name part goes ($name has the wrong value). If the user is unable to open the file, the problem could be a few things but is most likely additional output from the server like a php error or unnecessary whitespace. To find the issue, we would likely need to see more code as there really isn't anything in the code you posted.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn I have posted the whole script. Hope it helps. The name variable contains the filename.